# calculations inside do while are not working properly

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Inside this do while loop, the calculations to calculate yearly average and the yearly low average temps and yearly high average temps are not working properly.

```
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    //extract Month name from file
    month = inFile.next();
    //Remove comma for better presentation
    String   formatMonth = month.replace(',', ' ');
    //calculate high temperature from text file
    highTemp  = inFile.nextDouble();
    //extract low temperature file from text file
    lowTemp = inFile.nextDouble();
    //Calculate averaget Temperature from values
    averageTemp = (highTemp + lowTemp)/2;
    //Calculate Range
    range = (highTemp - lowTemp);
    //Calculate low temperature
    minTemp = Math.min(minTemp, lowTemp);
    //Calculate high temperature
    maxTemp = Math.max(maxTemp, highTemp);
    //Sum up high temperatures
    highSum =+ highTemp;
    //Sum up low Temperatures
    lowSum =+ lowTemp;
    //calculate yearly sum
    yearlySum =+ averageTemp;
    //Calculate average of all the high temperatures
    totalAvgHigh = highSum/12;
    //Calculate average of all low temperatures
    totalAvgLow = lowSum/12;
    //Calculate the average of the years
    totalAvgYearly = yearlySum/12;
    //Calculate averge of the range
    totalRangeAvg = (highSum +lowSum)/12;

    System.out.println(formatMonth + "   |     " + highTemp + "         |       " + lowTemp + "     |      " + averageTemp + "    |    " + range );
    outFile.println(formatMonth + "   |           " + highTemp + "         |       " + lowTemp + "     |      " + averageTemp + "    |    " + range );
}

//Print out calculated values
System.out.print("Average High Temps: " + totalAvgHigh + " Average Low Temps: " + totalAvgLow + " Total Average: " + totalAvgYearly + " Total Range Average: " + totalRangeAvg);
System.out.println("High Temp " + maxTemp);
System.out.println("Low Temp " + minTemp);
outFile.print("Average High Temps: " + totalAvgHigh + " Average Low Temps: " + totalAvgLow + " Total Average: " + totalAvgYearly + " Total Range Average: " + totalRangeAvg);
outFile.println("High Temp " + maxTemp);
outFile.println("Low Temp " + minTemp);
```

the output is this:

```
enter code here:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Month    |  High Temperature | Low Temperature | Average Temperature | Range 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
January    |     72.0         |       -12.0     |      30.0    |    84.0
February   |     75.0         |       -5.0     |      35.0    |    80.0
March    |     80.0         |       8.0     |      44.0    |    72.0
April    |     98.0         |       15.0     |      56.5    |    83.0
May    |     98.0         |       29.0     |      63.5    |    69.0
June    |     100.0         |       28.0     |      64.0    |    72.0
July    |     103.0         |       48.0     |      75.5    |    55.0
August    |     106.0         |       40.0     |      73.0    |    66.0
September    |     102.0         |       35.0     |      68.5    |    67.0
October    |     90.0         |       26.0     |      58.0    |    64.0
November    |     85.0         |       14.0     |      49.5    |    71.0
December    |     76.0         |       -10.0     |      33.0    |    86.0
Average High Temps: 6.333333333333333 Average Low Temps: -0.8333333333333334 Total Average: 2.75 Total Range Average: 5.5High Temp 1.7976931348623157E308
Low Temp -12.0
```

Comment: Ok, have you tried printing out intermediate values, or stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: No matter what a professor tells you, there is no need to comment every single line.

Comment: Hint: 76/12 = 6.33333333 and -10/12 = -0.83333333.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `+=` instead of `=+`.  I've never seen that before...

Comment: There is no such thing as `=+`. `foo =+ bar` is `foo = +bar` is `foo = bar`. No wonders the outcome isn't the expected.

Comment: I'm surprised `=+` even compiles (considering I cannot imagine it being used in a way other than by accident...)

Comment: @glowcoder  I'm surprised too, but I imagine it works for the reason @Femaref points out.  Nobody ever said the compilers job was to prevent you from making mistakes...

Comment: @Chris, that last point is debatable. Consider that implements (generics) and removes (goto) some features for the purpose of preventing bugs.

Comment: @Chris That's not to say that I think waiting for the compiler to fix your mistakes is an excuse for not knowing what your code does! Of the millions of potential mistakes we programmers can make, I expect a compiler to be able to catch a couple hundred at best.